# Pivot cycle through filters and print to new excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to run through the different filter options on my pivot table and print each result to a new excel doc. 
Below is what i have so for it worked very well when I had it exporting to PDF. 
I would like the new excel to have only the workbook with the pivot table, have the formatting around the table and the filter to be stuck so you can't see the other options.

is this possible?

thank you for your help

More info:
this pivot table runs through outstanding invoices to produce a customer statement, the filter it needs to run through is the customer name. 
Originally i would run the different pivot options and print as PDFs. As I was doing it to PDF the company logo was in the header of the worksheet, but it would show in the PDF version. Also as it was going to PDF i was able to set the print area of the worksheet to cut out the pivot slicers from the PDF.
this is what i used to use for this

```
With pf
.ClearAllFilters
For Each pi In .PivotItems
.CurrentPage = pi.Name
wksSource.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=strPath & pi.Name & ".pdf"
Next pi
.ClearAllFilters
End With
End Sub
```

As i now need to produce them in excel format i don't now how to change the code to do this. I have moved the company logo to the sheet so it will be visibly in excel version. Also i still have pivot slicers on the sheet that i don't want to show up on the statements.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you expect as output and what you actually have yet. I think a visual example would help a lot. The code example should be minimal and only contain relevant parts for what you want to achieve and have done so far on this task.

Comment: i have changed the original question, please let me know if more info will help.

Comment: if I understand right, that you only like to save the workbook into another excel file, then maybe the `Workbook.SaveAs` method might be what you are looking for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas this seems to support the following file formats https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat and not only PDF and XPS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfixedformattype like `Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat

Comment: I have tried using the line below:                                                                                    
ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs Filename:=strPath & Pi.Name & ".xlsx"                         But when i tried to open the created excel it can't be opened the error is:                  "excel cannot open the file because the file format of file extension is not valid. verify that the file has not been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file"